# Login to Skype from terminal or any other way

Tags: command-line, skype

Please let me know if anybody knows how to login to Skype on Linux Mint from terminal or any other way?

I have tried a lot but nothing found.

```
Desktop # ./skype.desktop
./skype.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
./skype.desktop: line 3: Internet: command not found
./skype.desktop: line 4: fg: no job control
./skype.desktop: line 9: Application: command not found
./skype.desktop: line 11: X-KDE-Protocols=skype: command not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `skype.desktop` files are not meant for you to run. To invoke `skype` you should be able to simply type `skype` in your terminal or run it via the full path here:

```
$ /usr/bin/skype
```

Files that end in a `.desktop` are configuration files for your desktop, not for you to execute directly. See here for example:

```
$ more /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype
Comment=Skype Internet Telephony
Exec=skype %U
Icon=skype.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/skype;
X-KDE-Protocols=skype
```

You could try using `gnome-open ./skype.desktop` or `xdg-open ./skype.desktop`. These used to work, but there appears to be a bug that's been present for some time, which breaks these 2 commands ability to process `.desktop` files. See this AU Q&A titled: [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) for more on this.

#### exo-open

Using `exo-open ./skype.desktop` worked for me. `exo-open` is part of the Xfce DE, but will properly invoke the `.desktop` files.

```
$ exo-open /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

#### gtk-launch

Using `gtk-launch skype.desktop /path/to/desktop/file` also works.

```
$ gtk-launch skype.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

#### Command line login

If you take a look at the output of `skype --help`:

```
--pipelogin     Command line login. "echo username password | skype --pipelogin"
```

So you could achieve what you want like so:

```
$ echo username password | skype --pipelogin
```

Comment: @KarmjeetSingh - glad to help, thanks for the Q!

Answer (score 1):

In my case(Linux Mint 17.2, based on Ubuntu 14.04) the way to just launch Skype from command line is:

```
$ skypeforlinux
```

Which is listed in:

```
$ /usr/bin/skypeforlinux
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer systems (I'm running PopOS 20.10) where installation is done via [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.skype.Client), you can start Skype using:

```
flatpak run com.skype.Client
```

Also, `flatpak list` will show you installed flatpak binaries.